# How to import identity operations in scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz, traits

`syntax.IdOps` seems to have no "companion" object to import its implicits (see, [selfless pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/selfless_trait_pattern.html)), so it's hard to use that in REPL for example:

```
scala> val selfish = new scalaz.syntax.ToIdOps{} //I don't want to do this, it feels wrong
selfish: scalaz.syntax.ToIdOps = $anon$1@1adfe356

scala> import selfish._
import selfish._
```

Is there a way to import it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.2/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/Syntax.scala#L117

You can use `scalaz.syntax.id` instead of `new scalaz.syntax.ToIdOps{}`

```
import scalaz.syntax.id._
```

Comment: Oh! I've missed `ToIdOpsDeprecated` when looking for object. Thanks!

Comment: another option is to add all syntaxes: `import scalaz.syntax.all._`